# Facebook Like API

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using [facebook sdk](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com). After the user authenticates to my application, I have his 'Likes' permission.

Can I add "like" to a product page automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking, but here is some information which may be relevant.

Requesting a 'user_likes' permission will give you access the items a user has previously liked.

In order to programatically like something, (I believe) that entity has to exist within facebook - taken from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

> /OBJECT_ID/likes  Like the given object (if it has a /likes connection)

To do this you'll have to request the 'publish_stream' permission and then do something like:

```
// untested!
var app = new FacebookApp();
app.Post("OBJECT_ID/likes");
```

Failing that you'll have to add a like button  (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) where the user will have to click themselves

Hope that helps :)

Comment: hi thanks but mybyee i didnt be clear enough , i want to do the like opration automatic..i dont want the user to click the like button i want it will be automatic like to the my bussines facebook page

Comment: Ok, then try the code snippet, using the facebook page id as 'OBJECT_ID' :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add like buttons to product pages on your site. You are looking for the open graph api.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/